# Smart contract error Error: transaction failed

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ethers.js, hardhat

I deployed smart contract to testnet and i got error can someone help me debug this

Code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

interface IERC3156FlashBorrower {
    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external returns (bytes32);
}

contract FlashBorrower2 is Context, ReentrancyGuard, IERC3156FlashBorrower {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    address private owner;
    uint256 public constant MAX_INT = type(uint256).max;
    address USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier OnlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external override nonReentrant returns (bytes32) {
        IERC20(token).approve(msg.sender, MAX_INT);
        uint256 amountOutExpected;
        uint256 amountOutExpected2;
        (amountOutExpected, amountOutExpected2) = abi.decode(
            data,
            (uint256, uint256)
        );
        address UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
        address SUSHISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F;

        IUniswapV2Router02 uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS
        );
        IUniswapV2Router02 sushiSwapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            SUSHISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS
        );

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = token;
        path[1] = USDC;

        uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amount,
            amountOutExpected,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        address[] memory path2 = new address[](2);
        path2[0] = USDC;
        path2[1] = token;

        sushiSwapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            IERC20(USDC).balanceOf(address(this)),
            amountOutExpected2,
            path2,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        return keccak256("ERC3156FlashBorrower.onFlashLoan");
    }

    function withdrawWETH(address WETH) external OnlyOwner {
        require(
            IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)) > 0,
            "No funds to withdraw"
        );
        IERC20(WETH).transfer(owner, IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)));
    }
}
```

ERROR

````
Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transactionHash="0x05b56cf7dde5495ec7ff5ed13bf1a64f45481e19c20fd948b69f56a0669e9a7d", transaction={"type":2,"chainId":11155111,"nonce":21,"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x010aaeb4f1"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x010aaeb4f1"},"gasPrice":null,"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x017d7840"},"to":"0xD6011CC83d2Be6db63105574e230D8314307518e","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"data":"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","accessList":[],"hash":"0x05b56cf7dde5495ec7ff5ed13bf1a64f45481e19c20fd948b69f56a0669e9a7d","v":0,"r":"0x820c7007b97f38ff6bae728d1a10e73f952520545193d186acd53bc6c4690502","s":"0x57dd20396db78e0ef5ea6711610a40fd7517f0203403483f1df94cae7835139d","from":"0x52E48123Dd1d3A2DbFcf60670D5d4d192Fd0bd78","confirmations":0}, receipt={"to":"0xD6011CC83d2Be6db63105574e230D8314307518e","from":"0x52E48123Dd1d3A2DbFcf60670D5d4d192Fd0bd78","contractAddress":null,"transactionIndex":8,"gasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x7d7d"},"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","blockHash":"0x45e6ea1c2bac4b5ce14fb7d44b41ed4efccb2cf829da5a673962e4b8c5f5be4d","transactionHash":"0x05b56cf7dde5495ec7ff5ed13bf1a64f45481e19c20fd948b69f56a0669e9a7d","logs":[],"blockNumber":4874132,"confirmations":1,"cumulativeGasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x03885f"},"effectiveGasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x010aaeb4f1"},"status":0,"type":2,"byzantium":true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (E:\TESTNETSANDWITCH\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (E:\TESTNETSANDWITCH\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (E:\TESTNETSANDWITCH\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\base-provider.ts:1549:24)
    at step (E:\TESTNETSANDWITCH\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (E:\TESTNETSANDWITCH\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (E:\TESTNETSANDWITCH\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:20:58) {
  reason: 'transaction failed',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  transactionHash: '0x05b56cf7dde5495ec7ff5ed13bf1a64f45481e19c20fd948b69f56a0669e9a7d',
  transaction: {
    type: 2,
    chainId: 11155111,
    nonce: 21,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x010aaeb4f1', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x010aaeb4f1', _isBigNumber: true },
    gasPrice: null,
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x017d7840', _isBigNumber: true },
    to: '0xD6011CC83d2Be6db63105574e230D8314307518e',
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
    data: '0x23e30c8b000000000000000000000000d6011cc83d2be6db63105574e230d8314307518e000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b1ae4d6e2ef500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    accessList: [],
    hash: '0x05b56cf7dde5495ec7ff5ed13bf1a64f45481e19c20fd948b69f56a0669e9a7d',
    v: 0,
    r: '0x820c7007b97f38ff6bae728d1a10e73f952520545193d186acd53bc6c4690502',
    s: '0x57dd20396db78e0ef5ea6711610a40fd7517f0203403483f1df94cae7835139d',
    from: '0x52E48123Dd1d3A2DbFcf60670D5d4d192Fd0bd78',
    confirmations: 0,
    wait: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  receipt: {
    to: '0xD6011CC83d2Be6db63105574e230D8314307518e',
    from: '0x52E48123Dd1d3A2DbFcf60670D5d4d192Fd0bd78',
    contractAddress: null,
    transactionIndex: 8,
    gasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0x7d7d', _isBigNumber: true },
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    blockHash: '0x45e6ea1c2bac4b5ce14fb7d44b41ed4efccb2cf829da5a673962e4b8c5f5be4d',
    transactionHash: '0x05b56cf7dde5495ec7ff5ed13bf1a64f45481e19c20fd948b69f56a0669e9a7d',
    logs: [],
    blockNumber: 4874132,
    confirmations: 1,
    cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0x03885f', _isBigNumber: true },
    effectiveGasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x010aaeb4f1', _isBigNumber: true },
    status: 0,
    type: 2,
    byzantium: true
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is related to a specific opcode, PUSH0(0x5f), introduced in Solidity version 0.8.20. Unfortunately, this opcode is not currently supported by the Binance Smart Chain (BSC). To resolve this, you can use Solidity versions 0.8.18 or 0.8.19 instead, as these versions do not include the problematic opcode and are compatible with BSC. By downgrading your Solidity version to either 0.8.18 or 0.8.19, you should be able to avoid the opcode compatibility issue on the BSC platform.